# finding and understanding how to find closure?

Tags: general-topology

X be real line and $B$ is subset of $X$

> For $B=\{1/n ;n\in \mathbb{Z}_+ \}$ find the closure of $B$.

The closure of $A$ is defined as the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$.

I want to know how to do these kind of question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? In particular, do you know other, equivalent definitions of the closure?

Comment: I don't know any other definition, in the book the definition was given and below that some examples are given.@jendrik stelzner

Comment: Closure in what topological space?

Comment: edited @G.Sassatelli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limits point of $B$ is $0$, thus $\bar{B} = B \cup \text{{0}}$